# Determining when the user clicks the x - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to programmatically decide if the user has clicked the top right "x" button while using a form in visual basic.

I have tried:

```
Private Sub nameOfForm_Exit()
     'code goes here
End Sub
```

Which has been unsuccessful. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: QueryClose Event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278635.aspx (even tells you if the user pressed X or if the form was closed programmatically or... etc. and allows you to prevent the form from closing, if you so choose)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    MsgBox "Good bye"

    '/ To prevent user from closing the form
    '/ Set cancel to True

    Cancel = True

    MsgBox "You can't close me!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]
You can't invent your own terms like "Exit". You have to take them in the combo boxes above (known as Events). Since your event pertains to the Userform itself, you need to choose Userform in the left combo box. You will also see all the controls your userform has, they each have a set of events.

As has been said QueryClose will refer to the red X in the top right corner. You also have Deactivate, which will happen whenever the UserForm loses focus (if it is ModeLess, meaning that a user can click the sheet behind the userform without closing it, this will trigger Deactivate) and Terminate, which occurs after the Userform closes with QueryClose.